# Locally added file under the Git version control system

Tags: init-file, git

Whenever I save my `main.el` file, I get the following error.

```
apply: Args out of range: #("Git@" 0 4 (help-echo "Locally added file under the Git version control system" face vc-locally-added-state)), 0, 7
```

The debug stack looks like this:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (args-out-of-range #("Git@" 0 4 (help-echo "Locally added file under the Git version control system" face vc-locally-added-state)) 0 7)
  vc-git-mode-line-string("~/emacs_environment/elisp/main.el")
  apply(vc-git-mode-line-string "~/emacs_environment/elisp/main.el")
  vc-call-backend(Git mode-line-string "~/emacs_environment/elisp/main.el")
  vc-mode-line("~/emacs_environment/elisp/main.el" Git)
  vc-find-file-hook()
  run-hooks(find-file-hook)
  after-find-file(nil t)
  find-file-noselect-1(#<buffer main.el> "~/emacs_environment/elisp/main.el" nil nil "~/emacs_environment/elisp/main.el" (4325419 2050))
  find-file-noselect("~/emacs_environment/elisp/main.el" nil nil)
  ido-file-internal(raise-frame)
  ido-find-file()
  funcall-interactively(ido-find-file)
  #<subr call-interactively>(ido-find-file nil nil)
  ad-Advice-call-interactively(#<subr call-interactively> ido-find-file nil nil)
  apply(ad-Advice-call-interactively #<subr call-interactively> (ido-find-file nil nil))
  call-interactively(ido-find-file nil nil)
  command-execute(ido-find-file)
```

I get the same error whenever I open the buffer. The message displays and the buffer loads, but it doesn't open in the current window. I have to do that explicitly with <kbd>C-x C-b</kbd>.

My `.emacs` looks like this.

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/emacs_environment/elisp")
(require 'main)
```

This loads the `main.el` library for me, which itself loads more specific `.el` libraries. I do it this way so that I can sync the `emacs_environment` directory across computers.

I get the same error even if I comment out everything in the `main.el` file.

My `emacs_environment` directory is a Git repository, and I have magit installed.

My Emacs version is `GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.4.2) of 2015-01-09 on lgw01-05`.

How can I eliminate the error and have my `main.el` file open normally?

Comment: What is your Emacs version?

Comment: `version` returns `GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.4.2) of 2015-01-09 on lgw01-05`

Comment: This is probably not magit. I'd start by running emacs with `--debug-init` and see where the error is coming from. Else, set `debug-on-error` to `t` and next time you save the file, the stacktrace will show you the reason for why it happens.

Comment: I don't have any errors on init though.

Comment: Then do `M-x` `toggle-debug-on-error` after your init.

Comment: I have done so and added the debug stack to the question. I got a silent -1 on this question. Advice on how to improve it is appreciated.

Comment: +1 to counter the silenet -1. This looks like a reasonable question to me, although likely local to @MatthewPiziak configuration.

Comment: Thank you. I have already flagged for moderator attention, so that they can close it if they feel it is too localized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following to my `main.el`:

```
;; disable vc-git
(setq vc-handled-backends ())
```

This works for me since I use `magit` instead of `vc-git`, but I admit that it's a bit of a nuclear option.

I believe the problem was due to a bug in snapshot, since the problem disappeared when I installed a stable Emacs 24.4.

Comment: `(vc-mode -1)` should also do it.

Comment: I tried it, but it seems that `(vc-mode -1)` does not eliminate the problem.

Comment: Do you have a stable version i.e. 24.4 installed? I'd run that and see if you get the same problem. If you don't, then it is likely due to some instability in current dev branch. I would also see about updating your emacs as 6+ weeks for a dev version is pretty old

Comment: I tried 24.4 stable and the problem disappeared. I'm going to chalk it up to snapshot instability.